# Add columns to the crystal report dynamically

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

I am using Visual Studio and Crystal Report 2010, I need my rpt file dynamically add columns, if you insert such a new company then will get a new column in the report, as I can do this.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this is probably to dynamically generate the report itself. There are a large number of questions and answers on that subject here and it will allow you to have complete control over the whole report

Answer (score 0):

in the end find a solution, using the option of Crystal Report Cross Tab, this allowed me to say that the values ​​of a column in my DataSet would be my report columns and values ​​of another column would be the rows of the report, it worked well.